# getchar() != ' ' and getchar() = ' '

Tags: c, loops, scanf, getchar, putchar

I am having trouble understanding what `getchar() != ' '` and `getchar() = ' '` are doing in my code.
Why do there need to be opposites.
The user may input extra spaces between the first name and last, and before the first name and after the last name.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char c, initial;

    printf("Enter a first and last name: ");
    scanf(" %c", &initial);
    printf("%c\n", initial);
    while ((c = getchar()) != ' ')
        ;

    while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
        ;

    do {
        putchar(c);
    } while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != ' ');

    printf(", %c.\n", initial);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please copy-paste your code

Comment: Without even looking at your code, I can tell you that any appearance of `getchar() = ' '` serves only one purpose: to cause compilation to fail.

Comment: In any case, if it's your code then how do you not at least know what purposes its various bits  are *supposed* to serve?

Comment: It's not my code. I am looking at someone else's answer for the same exercise in a programming textbook.

The code does not fail though and works perfectly.

Comment: @Nick  "what getchar() != ' ' and getchar() = ' ' are doing in my code" Remove them immediately! :)

Comment: your question states: `and getchar() = ' '`  which would not compile.  However the code is correct with:  `while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code snippet

```
scanf(" %c", &initial);
// printf("%c\n", initial); <== remove this statement
while ((c = getchar()) != ' ')
    ;
```

The first letter of the first name is read and other letters are skipped.

This loop

```
while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
    ;
```

skips spaces between the first name and the second name.

This loop

```
do {
    putchar(c);
} while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != ' ');
```

outputs all letters of the second name.

And at last the first letter of the first name is outputted after the full second name.

So if you entered for example

```
Nick     Fisher
```

then the output should be

```
Fisher, N.
```

Take into account that you should remove the statement

```
printf("%c\n", initial);
```

it is a redundant statement.

Comment: thank you very very much! This explains it perfectly

Comment: The original code won't work as intended if there are leading white-space characters in the line entered.

Comment: @LxerLx Why did you decide so? The leading white spaces are skipped.

Comment: the output is not what will actually happen.  The first line of the output will be the initial due to: `printf("%c\n", initial);`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You are right. I've overlooked the space before `%c`.

Comment: Yes the redundant statement was added so I could try to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != ' ')
    ;

while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
    ;
```

the first `while()` loop consumes the rest of the first name

the second `while()` loop consumes the spaces between the first and last name.

Answer (score 0):

isn't there a problem using a char for initial and then writing a lot of characters into it? I think your using not allocated memory for the name.
And the first `printf("%c\n", initial);` should generate an output of the first character entered.

Soooo...
Input: 
Nick   Fisher
Output:

N
Fisher, N.
or:
Fisher, N.
or:
 program crash because of forbidden memory access

regards André